# base64 to image using Django Rest Framework (DRF)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am writing API, which accepts base64-encoded string and saves it as an image. It is trivial to do using standard library tools, such as base64, but how can I do it using viewsets.ModelViewSet? Which field should I modify? (I also have been trying to do it using custom middleware, but it is prohibited, since querydict cannot be modified)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Base64ImageField from drf_extra_fields.

just add this in your serializer.

```
class YourImageSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    img_field = Base64ImageField()
```

you can also use this with ModelSerializer

check this out https://github.com/Hipo/drf-extra-fields

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Should I modify standard django models.ImageField in my models.py file?

Comment: You don't need to do any change with models. just add Base64ImageField in your serializer then it will accept base64 image string.